# SNMP and UDP multicast

Tags: udp, snmp, multicast, net-snmp

Is it possible for an SNMP manager to send an snmpget multicast to all nodes in the network? Specifically is this supported by net-snmp? I cannot find anything on it being supported.

Comment: http://docs.sharpsnmp.com/en/latest/tutorials/device-discovery.html#simple-device-discovery-for-v1-and-v2c-ipv4 Generally speaking broadcast or multicast won't be the way for SNMP manager to manage or discover devices. You should still go the one-by-one approach.

Comment: 172.23.136<1-100> (include any IP address from 1 to 100 in 172.23.136/255.255.255.0)
172.23.135.* (include any IP address in 172.23.135/255.255.255.0); are these two items valid? Can I send SNMPgets to an entire subnet within one SNMP session?